# Finding the shortest path (between source and destination) with the least number of edges

Tags: c, graph, dijkstra

I am trying to write a program that finds a minimum-length path between a two vertices in a graph, selecting from among such paths one of those that traverses the fewest edges. I used Dijkstra's algorithm with several modifications (below).

The output supposed to be: `0->3->4`, but instead, my program prints `0->4`.
Why do I get the wrong output?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define INFINITY 9999
#define n 5
#define s 0
#define d 4

void Dijkstra(int Graph[n][n], int _n,int _s, int _d);

int main()
{
    int Graph[n][n] = {
        {0, 6, 5, 1, INFINITY},
        {6, 0, 3, INFINITY, INFINITY},
        {5, 3, 0, 2, 5},
        {1, INFINITY, 2, 0, 6},
        {INFINITY, INFINITY, 5, 6, 0}
    };

    Dijkstra(Graph,n,s,d);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void Dijkstra(int Graph[n][n], int _n,int _s, int _d)
{
    int distance[n], parent[n], visited[n], edge[n]={0}, mindistance,
            nextnode= _s, i, j,temp[n][n], res[n];

    //parent[] stores the predecessor of each node
    //edge[] stores the number of edged of every vertex's shortest path

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)       //create the temp matrix
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if (Graph[i][j] == INFINITY)
                temp[i][j] = INFINITY;
            else
                temp[i][j] = Graph[i][j];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        distance[i] = INFINITY;   //initialize distance
        parent[i] = _s;           //initialize parent
        visited[i] = 0;
        if (distance[i] > 0 && distance[i] < INFINITY)
            edge[i]++;
    }

    distance[_s] = 0;
    visited[_s] = 1;

    while (visited[_d] == 0)
    {
        //nextnode gives the node at minimum distance
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            mindistance = temp[_s][i] + distance[i];
            if (distance[i] < mindistance && !visited[i])
            {
                mindistance = distance[i];
                nextnode = i;
            }
        }

        //check if a better path exists through nextnode            
        visited[nextnode] = 1;

        if (nextnode != _d)
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                if (!visited[i])
                {
                    if (mindistance + Graph[nextnode][i] < distance[i])
                    {
                        distance[i] = mindistance + Graph[nextnode][i];
                        parent[i] = nextnode;
                        edge[i] = edge[nextnode] + 1;
                    }

                    if (mindistance + Graph[nextnode][i] == distance[i])
                    {
                        if (edge[i] >= edge[nextnode] + 1)

                        {
                            parent[i] = nextnode;
                            edge[i] = edge[nextnode] + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
    }

    //print the path 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        res[i] = 0;

    i = nextnode;

    while (i != _s)
    {
        res[i] = parent[i];
        i = parent[i];
    }

    printf("%d", _s);
    printf("->");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (res[i] != 0)
        {
            printf("%d", res[i]);
            printf("->");
        }
    }
    printf("%d", _d);
}
```

Comment: "shortest path" and "least number of edges" are two different things. You need to choose one or the other.

Comment: It doesn't print anything because the `while` loop never ends. But you've now changed the code and the question, so this is quicksand - it might trap me forever.

Comment: @user3386109, "shortest path" and "least number of edges" are exactly the same thing when all the edges have equal weight.  Of course, that special case affords some approaches that the general shortest path problem does not, but any approach that solves the general case (e.g. Dijkstra) must also solve the special case.

Comment: Thanks @John. Did you take the time to read the code in the question?

Comment: I am looking at the code now, @user3386109.

Comment: well, does anyone know why I get the wrong input?

Comment: You make a copy of your graph in variable `temp`, but you never modify either the original or the copy.  What, then, is the point of copying?

Comment: If you are using Dijkstra then it migth be an idea to check if there are no negative edges/cycles. You are using ints so that should be easy. Otherwise you could search for the Bellman-Ford algorithm which works with negative edges and detects cycles in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems in the loop where you choose the next node to traverse.  It is clearly incorrect to set

```
            mindistance = Graph[_s][i] + distance[i];
```

on each iteration, since you need `mindistance` to track the minimum observed distance *across iterations*.  Instead, *before* the loop you should set

```
        mindistance = INFINITY;
```

While we're looking at this loop, observe also that you ignore the edge count criterion in selecting the next node to traverse.  You need to use that criterion here, too, to ensure that you find a path that meets your criteria.

With those corrections, your program produces the expected output for me.

Do note, by the way, that this is still pretty straight-up Dijkstra.  The trick is to recognize that you're implementing a two-component distance measure.  The most-significant component is the path length (sum of edge weights), but the edge count is a secondary component by which ties are broken.  The *implementation* therefore looks a little different, but if you factored out the distance comparison and setting to separate functions then you wouldn't be able to tell the remainder apart from standard Dijkstra (simple variation).

Answer (score 0):

> I have edited my code, but I still get the same wrong output:
>
> ```
> #include<stdio.h>
> #include<conio.h>
>
> #define INFINITY 9999
> #define n 5
> #define s 0
> #define d 4
>
> void Dijkstra(int Graph[n][n], int _n,int _s, int _d);
>
> int main()
> {
>     int Graph[n][n]={{0,6,5,1,INFINITY},{6,0,3,INFINITY,INFINITY},{5,3,0,2,5},{1,INFINITY,2,0,6},{INFINITY,INFINITY,5,6,0}};
>
>     Dijkstra(Graph,n,s,d);
>     getchar();
>     return 0;
> }
>
> void Dijkstra(int Graph[n][n],int _n,int _s,int _d)
> {
>
>     int temp[n][n],distance[n],parent[n],visited[n],mindistance,nextnode,j,i;
>
>     //parent[] stores the predecessor of each node
>     //edge[] stores the number of edges in the shortest path from the source
>
>
>     //create the cost matrix
>     for(i=0;i<_n;i++)
>         for(j=0;j<_n;j++)
>                 temp[i][j]=Graph[i][j];
>
>
>     //initialize 
>     for(i=0;i<_n;i++)
>     {
>         distance[i]=INFINITY;
>         parent[i]=_s;
>         visited[i]=0;
>     }
>
>     distance[_s]=0;
>     visited[_s]=1;
>
>     nextnode=_s;
>
>     while(visited[_d]==0)
>     {
>         mindistance=INFINITY;
>
>         //nextnode gives the node at minimum distance
>         for(i=0;i<_n;i++)
>         {
>             distance[i]=temp[nextnode][i];
>             if(distance[i]<mindistance && !visited[i])
>             {
>                 mindistance=distance[i];
>                 nextnode=i;
>             }
>         }
>
>             //check if a better path exists through nextnode            
>             visited[nextnode]=1;
>             for(i=0;i<_n;i++)
>                 if(!visited[i])
>                     if(mindistance+temp[nextnode][i]<distance[i])
>                     {
>                         temp[nextnode][i]=mindistance+distance[i];
>                         parent[i]=nextnode;
>                     }
>     }
>
>     //print the path and distance of each node
>    i=_d;
>    printf("%d",i);
>         do
>         {
>
>                 i=parent[i];
>                 printf("<-%d",i);
>
>     }while(i!=_s);
> }
> ```

Just a few small changes are needed to get the supposed output; I commented on the code below:

```
…
    distance[_s]=0;
//  visited[_s]=1;  do not mark the initial node as visited - will select below
//  nextnode=_s;    no need here - will select as the node at minimum distance
    while (!visited[_d])
    {
        mindistance=INFINITY;
        //nextnode gives the node at minimum distance
        for (i=0; i<_n; i++)
        {
        //  distance[i]=temp[nextnode][i];  don't change tentative distance here
            if (distance[i]<mindistance && !visited[i])
            {
                mindistance=distance[i];
                nextnode=i;
            }
        }
        //check if a better path exists through nextnode            
        visited[nextnode]=1;
        for (i=0; i<_n; i++)
            if (!visited[i])
                if (mindistance+temp[nextnode][i]<distance[i])
                {
                //  temp[nextnode][i]=mindistance+distance[i];  other way round
                    distance[i]=mindistance+temp[nextnode][i];  // smaller
                    parent[i]=nextnode;
                }
    }
…
```